# Trying to convert mysql to mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, session, post, mysqli

I'm trying to convert my MySql code to MySqli. My MySql is working very good, but the MySqli code isn't working (it isn't giving results). I don't know what I did wrong, I'm a "Noob"Programmer. Can you guys please correct my mistakes.

This is my MySql code:

```
    <?php
session_start();
include 'dbh.php';

$name = $_POST['name'];
$desc = $_POST['desc'];
$placerId = $_SESSION['id'];
$null = "0";

if (isset($_SESSION['uid'])) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO adds (name, descr, placerId, imgURL)
            VALUES ('$name', '$desc', '$placerId', '$null')";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    $str = $_POST['keywords'];
    $arr =  explode(" ", $str);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM adds WHERE placerId='$placerId' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    $addId = $row['id'];

    //print all the value which are in the array
    foreach($arr as $keyword){

        $sql = "INSERT INTO keywords (placerId, productId, keyword)
                VALUES ('$placerId', '$addId', '$keyword')";
                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    }
```

And this is my MySqli code:

```
    $name = $_POST['name'];
$desc = $_POST['desc'];
$placerId = $_SESSION['id'];
$null = "0";

if (isset($_SESSION['uid'])) {

    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO adds (name, descr, placerId, imgURL) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)")) {

        // Bind the variables to the parameter as strings. 
        $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $name, $desc, $placerId, $null);

        // Execute the statement.
        $stmt->execute();

        // Close the prepared statement.
        $stmt->close();

    }

    $str = $_POST['keywords'];
    $arr =  explode(" ", $str);

    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id FROM adds WHERE placerId=? ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1")) {

        // Bind a variable to the parameter as a string. 
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $placerId);

        // Execute the statement.
        $stmt->execute();

        // Get the variables from the query.
        $stmt->bind_result($addId);

        // Fetch the data.
        $stmt->fetch();

        // Close the prepared statement.
        $stmt->close();

        foreach($arr as $keyword){

            if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO keywords (placerId, productId, keyword) VALUES (?, ?, ?)")) {

                // Bind the variables to the parameter as strings. 
                $stmt->bind_param("sss", $placerId, $addId, $keyword);

                // Execute the statement.
                $stmt->execute();

                // Close the prepared statement.
                $stmt->close();

            }
        }

    }
```

And the ($conn variable to connect to the database) code:

```
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "stp2");



if (!$conn) {

    die("Connection failed: ".mysqli_connect_error);

}
```

Comment: Code is updated!!!

Comment: you're using the wrong variable

Comment: [Enable mysqli errors.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662488/how-to-get-mysqli-error-in-different-environments)

Comment: Consider using PDO over mysqli, as for when you say the file "doesn't work", what does that mean, is there an error? is the row just not inserted with no error, what/

Comment: [Enable PHP errors.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display)

Comment: How do you mean, the wrong variable?

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: It's not working is not a descriptive explanation..  What error shows when you execute?

Comment: `$mysqli` != `$conn`.

Comment: `id` != `uid` too

Comment: It isn't showing any results.

Comment: I like what @zack6849 said - [PDO is the way to go!](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html)

Comment: Two reasons PDO is better: No crappy procedural interface that's easily confused with `mysql_query` and *named* placeholders. There's really no reason not to use it in a new project if you're struggling with `mysqli`.